# Using pytest how to have command line arguments pertain to specific tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have multiple tests in a directory (e.g, test_1.py, test_2.py, etc...).  Several of the tests need command line arguments while others don't.  One of the tests requires a command line argument so I need to set required=True in parser.addoptoin.  Some of the scripts do not require command line option.  The problem is when I want to run some of the tests as standalone, the scripts that don't require a command line option will no longer run because it says it is missing a required option.  How do I make command line options only apply to specific tests?

Here is my conftest.py file where I'm defining command line arguments

```
#conftest.py

def pytest_addoption(parser):
        parser.addoption(
                    "--isisfile", action="store", required=True,
                    help="YAML file defining ISIS Nbrs"
                )
        parser.addoption(
                    "--thresh", action="store", type=str, default="0s",
                    help="Threshold for ISIS Nbr last_state_change in format of 4h25s"
                )

@pytest.fixture
def isisfile(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--isisfile")

@pytest.fixture
def thresh(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--thresh")
```

Here is what happens when I run one of the individual pytests that "does not" require this command line argument:

```
pytest test_isis_nbrs_single.py
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: the following arguments are required: --isisfile
```

Comment: Instead of marking the command line option as `required`, maybe just arrange for the tests to be skipped if you haven't provided the necessary command line option?

Comment: Or implement a custom `pytest_collection_modifyitems` that will check whether tests requiring `isisfile` are scheduled to run and whether the option is in the config, and fail the execution early if the conditions aren't met.